# Need help on "Attempted to access.... ; index out of bounds because numel(...)=1" error

Tags: matlab

I needed to write a Newton method code on Matlab and processed through here. But when I try to use it, it gives this error after calculating a few times:

**Attempted to access df(8); index out of bounds because
numel(df)=1.**

**Error in newtonmethod (line 11)
    tz=ti-(f(ti)/df(ti));**

```
 function newtonmethod(f)
ti = 10;
tz = 8;
abstol = 0.0001;
counter = 0;
h=0.1;
df=((f(ti+h)-f(ti))/h);
while (abs(ti-tz)>abstol)
    ti=tz;
    tz=ti-(f(ti)/df(ti));
    counter=counter+1;
end
    ti=tz;
    fprintf(tz,'counter=',counter )
end
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because

```
df = (f(ti+h)-f(ti))/h;
```

computes a *single value* (at `ti = 10`), not define a function.

To be able to compute the value of `df = df(ti)` for any `ti`, you should define it as an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
df = @(ti) ((f(ti+h)-f(ti))/h);
```

by the way, why not use [central differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Forward.2C_backward.2C_and_central_differences)?

```
df = @(ti) (f(ti+h)-f(ti-h))/2/h;
```

for the same cost, you'll get an order of magnitude more accuracy...seems like a good deal to me :)

Comment: Thanks! It roselved issue but i am getting another error now: what can i do?


`Error using fprintf
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file
identifier.`

`Error in newtonmethod (line 15)
    fprintf(tz,'counter=',counter )`

Comment: @Profhero: yes, read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). The command `fprintf` writes data to a text file. Only if you give file ID `1` or `2` will it write to MATLAB's equivalent of `stdout` (normal text in the command window) or `stderr` (error text in the command window). It defaults to `stdout` when you omit the file ID.

Comment: thanks,i just wanted to sent a result to command window but it looks like i have a long way till learn matlab.